# MySQL Unique Exemption Case with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a set of data that lists when a User changes a Product, we look at who changed it, when, the old cost and new cost, and the percentage price difference.

I want to use a group by, where statement, or case to group by and exclude products that filters out changes were the change occurred in the same day and resulted in the original price staying.

So the situation I want to exclude would look like this:

```
| product  | Changed By | Old Price | New Price | % diff | Day Changed |
|----------|------------|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
| blue hat | me         |     94.00 |     95.00 |   1.05 | 2016-11-28  |
| blue hat | me         |     95.00 |     94.00 |   1.05 | 2016-11-28  |
```

Any ideas how to do this with MySql?

Comment: is there an unique id per row ? the dot before blue hat ist only a mistake ? how many changes per day are in table to find out the start and end price ?

Comment: There is a unique Id for each change that is made to a Product, and there is a ParentID that both Products share.

Comment: Don't know how many changes per day, we just started tracking price changes, but per record change there should be no more than two if a User did a mistake then reverted it, but it could be more changes if they revert it a number of times?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version for anyone who wants to see this done using subqueries, where's, and group by's.

This query looks at the changes to an Item's cost by a User for the span of 1 day, where it pulls in all the results from "yesterday". It lists all the changes for that day one asc and one desc and compares the price changes that way. If they are the same from the oldest change to the newest change of that say then it is exempted.

```
SELECT 
    us.Name,
    it.Name,
    pal.CS_PA_Line_Supplier__c as supplier_name,
    newest.NewValue as new_value,
    oldest.OldValue as old_value,
    ((newest.NewValue - oldest.OldValue) / oldest.OldValue) * 100 as Percentage
FROM    
(
    SELECT Id, Name, KNDY4__Item__c, CS_PA_Line_Supplier__c
    FROM KNDY4__Contract_Line__c
) pal

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            ParentId,
            CreatedById,
            CreatedDate,
            Field,
            NewValue
        FROM KNDY4__Contract_Line__History 
        WHERE CreatedDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
            AND CreatedDate < CURDATE() 
            AND Field='KNDY4__Negotiated_Price__c' 
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
    ) cd 
    GROUP BY ParentId
) newest 
    ON newest.ParentId=pal.Id

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            ParentId,
            OldValue
        FROM KNDY4__Contract_Line__History 
        WHERE CreatedDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
            AND CreatedDate < CURDATE() 
            AND Field='KNDY4__Negotiated_Price__c' 
        ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
    ) cd 
    GROUP BY ParentId 
) oldest 
    ON oldest.ParentId=pal.Id

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT Id, Name
    FROM User
) us 
    ON us.Id = newest.CreatedById

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT Id,Name 
    FROM KNDY4__Item__c
) it 
    ON it.Id=pal.KNDY4__Item__c

WHERE newest.ParentId IS NOT NULL 
    AND oldest.OldValue IS NOT NULL 
    AND newest.NewValue != oldest.OldValue
GROUP BY pal.KNDY4__Item__c, pal.CS_PA_Line_Supplier__c
ORDER BY it.Name ASC
```